# trying to understand the navigation service and getting an error

Tags: wpf

I Was trying to practice  Navigation service in Wpf and I am getting the following error

> 'Inkpad.Window1' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService'
>   and no extension method 'NavigationService' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'Inkpad.Window1' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added the assembly file `using System.Windows.Navigation;` and tried using a `<navigationWindow>` in the xaml, but got an error again saying I cant use it directly, which I didnt follow.

and the code I have added in my .cs is

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.NavigationService.Refresh();
}
```

Can any one please let me know how to over come this?

Comment: Have you added a reference to PresentationFramework.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the static method [NavigationService.GetNavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice.aspx):

```
NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this).Refresh();
```

Get more info on navigation in [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx).

Comment: Could you possibly post the complete xaml and c#, or some stripped-down example that shows the error? Or maybe upload the whole project somewhere?